# Returning top results for events in a competition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this

```
select R.EID, name, record, date, TYPE_NAME, METERS
from PLAYER P, REGISTER R, COMPETITION C, EVENT E, TYPE T, DISTANCE D
where P.PID=R.PID 
  and R.CID=C.CID 
  and R.EID=E.EID 
  and T.TYID=E.TYID 
  and D.DID=E.DID 
order by R.EID, record
```

It returns like this

```
EID  Name    Record       Date       Type_Name  Meters

1   HUONG   00:07:45    2011-03-22  Freestyle   100
1   NHUNG   00:16:25    2011-03-22  Freestyle   100
1   NULL    00:23:23    2011-03-22  Freestyle   100
1    HUY    00:23:43    2011-03-22  Freestyle   100
1   THAO    00:26:34    2011-03-22  Freestyle   100
1   TRANG   00:34:23    2011-03-22  Freestyle   100
1   HUNG    00:34:23    2011-03-22  Freestyle   100
1   CUONG   00:34:54    2011-03-22  Freestyle   100
1    BON    00:45:21    2011-03-22  Freestyle   100
2   HUNG    00:02:34    2011-03-22  Freestyle   800
2   NHUNG   00:15:25    2011-03-22  Freestyle   800
2    HUY    00:22:33    2011-03-22  Freestyle   800
2   TRANG   00:23:25    2011-03-22  Freestyle   800
```

For each Event in a competition, it keeps listing the EID multiple times for each swimmer who participated in that event.

All I want is for each event (EID) in each Competition (CID), to have a horizontal list of competitors who came 1st, 2nd, 3rd based on their record. A Competition has multiple events and each event can occur in multiple competitions so i define each event by EID and date of competition.

I have tried this

```
select x.EID, name, date, TYPE_NAME, METERS from 
(select R.EID, name, date, TYPE_NAME, METERS
from PLAYER P, REGISTER R, EVENT E, TYPE T, DISTANCE D
where P.PID=R.PID and R.CID=C.CID 
  and R.EID=E.EID 
  and T.TYID=E.TYID 
  and D.DID=E.DID 
order by R.EID, record) x
group by x.EID
```

Then create 3 views for 1st, 2nd, 3rd and using left join.

I have an idea that sorting the record by using `where record not in (1st record)` and keep doing this for the 2nd and 3rd but I think that if I have same record, it will eliminate some result.

I want the result something like this

```
 EID    Date         First   Second  Third

    1   2013-03-22  HUONG   NHUNG   NULL
    2   2013-03-22  HUNG    NHUNG   HUY
    3   2013-11-13  TRANG   DOAN    LINH
```

Comment: You should go to sqlfiddle.com, load up sample data and share what the final result set your trying to achieve is.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the prresentation layer/application-level code (e.g. a simple PHP loop on an ordered array)

Comment: Post your schema, sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Also, use explicit JOIN syntax. Sometimes I wish comma-join syntax had never been invented. :-(

Comment: please post sample data for your tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using sub-queries and the `LIMIT` keyword. Using `LIMIT` you won't miss any entries if they have the same record times.

### SQL

```
SELECT   r.CID, r.EID, c.date,
         (SELECT   p.name 
          FROM     REGISTER rr 
          JOIN     PLAYER p on rr.PID = p.PID 
          WHERE    rr.CID = r.CID and rr.EID = r.EID
          ORDER BY rr.record LIMIT 0,1) as 'First',
         (SELECT   p.name 
          FROM     REGISTER rr 
          JOIN     PLAYER p on rr.PID = p.PID 
          WHERE    rr.CID = r.CID and rr.EID = r.EID
          ORDER BY rr.record LIMIT 1,1) as 'Second',
         (SELECT   p.name 
          FROM     REGISTER rr 
          JOIN     PLAYER p on rr.PID = p.PID 
          WHERE    rr.CID = r.CID and rr.EID = r.EID
          ORDER BY rr.record LIMIT 2,1) as 'Third'
FROM     REGISTER r
JOIN     COMPETITION c on r.CID = c.CID
GROUP BY r.CID, r.EID, c.date
```

### Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPETITION
(
    CID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    date DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE TYPE
(
    TYID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    TYPE_NAME VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE DISTANCE
(
    DID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    METERS INT
);

CREATE TABLE EVENT
(
    EID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    TYID INT REFERENCES TYPE(TYID),
    DID INT REFERENCES DISTANCE(DID)
);

CREATE TABLE PLAYER
(
    PID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) 
);

CREATE TABLE REGISTER
(
    PID INT REFERENCES PLAYER(PID),
    CID INT REFERENCES COMPETITION(CID),
    EID INT REFERENCES EVENT(EID),
    record INT
);

INSERT INTO COMPETITION (date) values ('2011-03-22');
INSERT INTO TYPE (TYPE_NAME) values ('Freestyle');
INSERT INTO DISTANCE (METERS) values (100), (800);
INSERT INTO EVENT (TYID, DID) values (1,1), (1,2);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (name) values ('HUONG'), ('NHUNG'), ('NULL'), ('HUY'), ('THAO'), ('TRANG'), ('HUNG'), ('CUONG'), ('BON');
INSERT INTO REGISTER (PID, CID, EID, record) values 
(1, 1, 1, 465),
(2, 1, 1, 985),
(3, 1, 1, 1403),
(4, 1, 1, 1423),
(5, 1, 1, 1594),
(6, 1, 1, 2063),
(7, 1, 1, 2063),
(8, 1, 1, 2094),
(9, 1, 1, 2721),
(7, 1, 2, 154),
(2, 1, 2, 925),
(4, 1, 2, 1353),
(6, 1, 2, 1405);
```